# Swift Core Bluetooth, scanForPeripherals with specific UUIDS. Are the passed service UUIDs interdependent by "AND" or "OR"?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm working with Core Bluetooth in Swift and want to scan for devices. The function `scanForPeripherals(withServices sericeUUIDs: [CBUUID]?, options: [String: Any]? = nil)` offers the option to scan for devices with specific serviceUUIDs. How can I understand this filter?
Is it scanning for...

1. ... all devices that have **at least one** of these services, so basically the
   serviceUUIDs are interdependent by an "**OR**"?
   or
2. ... all devices that **have all the passed serviceUUIDS**, so basically the serviceUUIDs are interdependent by an "**AND**"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one of these services. OR.